# prove $\left\{a_{1} = 2, a_{n+1} = \frac{2+2a_{n}}{2+a_{n}} \right\}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am asked to prove that the following sequence converges and find it's limit.

$\left\{a_{1} = 2,  a_{n+1} = \frac{2+2a_{n}}{2+a_{n}} \right\}$

I assume I need to prove it's monotonic and bounded.
Also my guesstimate is that it's limit is $\sqrt2$.
I was able (I think) to prove it is bounded, by 0 and 3 for example.

I was not able to prove it is monotonic.

Please Help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hints: $\;a_{n+1} = \frac{2+2a_{n}}{2+a_{n}}=2 - \frac{2}{2+a_n}\,$, then:

- $1 \le a_n \le 2 \implies 1 \le a_{n+1} \le 2\,$, so the sequence is bounded
- $\require{cancel}a_{n+1}-a_{n} = \frac{2}{2+a_{n-1}} - \frac{2}{2+a_{n}} = \frac{2(a_n-a_{n-1})}{(2+a_n)(2+a_{n-1})}\,$, so the sequence is monotonic

Once determined that the sequence converges, you can pass to the limit and solve $a=\frac{2+2a}{2+a}\,$.

Comment: why can you deduce "so the sequence is monotonic"?

Comment: Very nice method.

Comment: @ikoikoia The denominator on the RHS is positive, which means that the differences $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ and $a_{n}-a_{n-1}$ have the same sign. In fact, since $a_1 \le a_0$, it follows that $a_1-a_0 \le 0\,$ $\implies a_2 - a_1 \le 0\,$ $\cdots \implies a_{n+1}-a_{n} \le 0$ for all $n$ i.e. the sequence is decreasing.

Comment: @ElieLouis Thanks. It doesn't *always* work (obviously), but it *is* nice when it does.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have an answer.

**Prove bounded below by $0$:**

Check base case, then assume $a_{n} > 0$.

It follows that:

$a_{n+1} = \frac{2+2a_{n}}{2+a_{n}}>0$

**Prove monotonic for all n:**

Check base base, then assume 
$a_{n+1} < a_{n}$.

It follows that:

$2 +2a_{n+1} + a_{n} + a_{n}a_{n+1} < 2 +2a_{n} + a_{n+1} + a_{n}a_{n+1}$

$(1 + a_{n+1})(2 + a_{n}) < (1 + a_{n})(2 + a_{n+1})$

$\frac{2+2a_{n + 1}}{2+a_{n+1}} < \frac{2 + 2a_{n}}{2 + a_{n}}
$

Which is:

$a_{n+2} < a_{n+1}$

Comment: Looks good to me (+1).

Comment: Great to see the OP take stuff in and respond with their own answer, (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use induction twice. We have:
$$a_{n+1} - a_{n} = \frac{2-a_{n}^2}{2+a_{n}}$$
You will have a decreasing sequence as long as $a(n) \geq \sqrt{2}$.

Edit: as you want.

So, we compute:
$$a_{n+1}^2 - 2 = \frac{2(a_{n}^2-2)}{(a_{n}+1)^2}$$
Can you see why this is positive?

Now, you can deduce that the sequence converges, and thus that $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ tends to $0$, so that $2-a_{n}^2 = 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Another hint please? I keep going around in circles with the algebra :(

Comment: I've added more information. The idea here is as you said, to show that the sequence is decreasing (and bounded below). Now all you need to know is that $a_{n} \geq \sqrt{2}$. You can see this by applying induction again. There is no reason whatsoever why induction should not lead to this result if the result is true.

Answer (score 0):

$a_{n+1} 
= \frac{2+2a_{n}}{2+a_{n}}
$
so
$a_{n+1}^2 
= \frac{4+8a_{n}+4a_n^2}{4+4a_n+a_n^2}
$
so
$a_{n+1}^2 -2
= \frac{4+8a_{n}+4a_n^2-8-8a_n-2a_n^2}{4+4a_n+a_n^2}
= \frac{-4+2a_n^2}{4+4a_n+a_n^2}
= 2\frac{a_n^2-2}{(a_n+2)^2}
$
so
$\frac{a_{n+1}^2 -2}{a_n^2-2}
= \frac{2}{(a_n+2)^2}
\lt \frac12
$
since
$a_n > 0$.

Therefore
$a_n^2-2
\to 0$
so
$a_n \to
\sqrt{2}$.

More directly,

$\begin{array}\\
a_{n+1}-\sqrt{2} 
&= \frac{2+2a_{n}-2\sqrt{2}-a_n\sqrt{2}}{2+a_{n}}\\
&= \frac{(2-\sqrt{2})a_{n}-2(\sqrt{2}-1)}{2+a_{n}}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)a_{n}-2(\sqrt{2}-1)}{2+a_{n}}\\
&= (\sqrt{2}-1)\frac{\sqrt{2}a_{n}-2}{2+a_{n}}\\
&= \sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)\frac{a_{n}-\sqrt{2}}{2+a_{n}}\\
&= (2-\sqrt{2})\frac{a_{n}-\sqrt{2}}{2+a_{n}}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{a_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}}{a_{n}-\sqrt{2}} 
&= \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2+a_{n}}\\
\text{so}\\
|\dfrac{a_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}}{a_{n}-\sqrt{2}}| 
&= |\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2+a_{n}}|\\
&\lt |\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}|\\
&= |1-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}|\\
&\lt \frac12
\end{array}
$

so, again
$a_n \to \sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

First, we prove by induction that $\text{ for all } n \ge 1 \text{, } \, a_n^2 \gt 2$ (we will see why shortly):

The base case holds since $2^2 \gt 2$.

Assume for a fixed $n$ that

$\tag 1 a_n^2 \gt 2$
Then 
$\quad a_{n+1}^2 \gt 2 \; \text{ iff }$
$\quad {(\frac{2 + 2 a_n} {2 + a_n})}^2 \gt 2 \; \text{ iff }$
$\quad (4 + 8 a_n + 4 a_n^2) \gt 2(4 + 4 a_n + a_n^2) \; \text{ iff }$
$\tag 2 2 a_n^2 \gt 4 $

But (1) implies (2) (multiply both sides of (1) by 2), so (1) is true for all $n \ge 1$.

Now for any number $a \gt -2$, simple algebra/arithmetic shows that

$\tag 3 \frac{2+2a}{2+a} \lt a \text{ iff } 2 \lt a^2$

So the sequence is strictly decreasing. Also, since $a_1 = 2$ and using (1), we can also conclude that the sequence assumes values in the closed interval $[1,2]$. So it is a convergent sequence. By using properties of limits one can show that the limit is $\sqrt 2$.
Hint: recast (3) to the purpose at hand.